# ASP.NET MVC app gives 404 on all routes after deleting and re-adding it in IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

If I go to the root of the app:

```
http://localhost:31503
```

I get a 404.

If I go to a subpage:

```
http://localhost:31503/User/Reset
```

I also get a 404.

I'm thinking this might have to do with my previously deleting and re-adding it in IIS; maybe there was some setting I had set to make it work and now that I recreated it from scratch that setting is no longer set? But what setting could it be?

edit: if I change this setting in IIS: `.NET Compilation > Default Language` from VB to C# then I get a blank page instead of a 404 for `http://localhost:31503` and the expected behavior for `http://localhost:31503/User/Reset`... or not? now it's not working again, maybe I accidentally ran it in Visual Studio? Or maybe trying to access it via https to test that out broke it...

I also noticed that my app's favicon does appear in the browser, so it's not like nothing at all is there... And if I run it in Visual Studio (ctrl-F5) it runs just fine, provided that I disable the app in IIS where it is using the same port.

Comment: I suggest you could try to check you have installed the right asp.net version firstly. Then, I suggest you could check if you have enabled some special module in your web.config file.

Comment: I have ASP.NET version 4.8 installed; the only other option is 3.5, and I'm pretty sure this app is supposed to be using 4.x. As for special modules - what kind of modules are you talking about @BrandoZhang? Where would I find them? I don't think I've changed anything like that recently...